# To find the SUM of each products in the different store/warehouse by using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want support  to find the total quantity of each products in 2 different store as you can see attached two table below by using Php.

[image: This is the table of stock]

[image: This is the output i expected]

this code i had tried is not working, but it get me the only total of Product as you can see on the second output table, but not total per each store

```
       <table class="table" id="manageStockStatus">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Product Name</th>


                        <th>Qty-office</th>
                        <th>Qty-Yard</th>
                        <th>T-Qyt</th>
                        <th>Size/Type</th>

                    </tr>
                <?php

    $sql = "SELECT  SUM(quantity) AS Tq, (SELECT product_name 
 from product where stock.product_id=product_id) as pname FROM `stock` GROUP BY product_id ";
                 $result = $connect->query($sql);

               while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
               $Productname=$row['pname'];
               $Tqnty=$row['Tq'];
                // $Tqnty=$row['Tq'];
                // $office=$row[];
                // $yard=$row['yard'];

               ?>
                </thead>

    <td><?php echo $Productname;?> </td>
    <td><!-- <?php echo $office;?> --></td>
    <td><!-- <?php echo $yard;?> --></td>
    <td><span class="badge"><?php echo $Tqnty; ?></span></td>
    <td></td>

    </tr> 

     <?php }?>
    </table>
    <!-- /table -->

</div> <!-- /panel-body -->
</div> <!-- /panel -->      
</div> <!-- /col-md-12 -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a left JOIN and doing a `group by stock.product_id,store`:

```
SELECT  stock.product_id as id,product_name as pname,store,SUM(quantity) AS Tq
FROM `stock` left join product on stock.product_id=product.product_id
group by stock.product_id,store
```

This way, in your while loop you can have:

```
       while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
           $Productname=$row['pname'];
           $Tqnty=$row['Tq'];
           $office=$row['store']; 
       ?>
```

**EDIT**

Then you can use CASE like this:

```
SELECT  stock.product_id as id,product.product_name as pname,
        sum(case 
                when store=1 then quantity
                else 0
            end) as office,
        sum(case 
                when store=2 then quantity
                else 0
            end) as yard
FROM `stock`  left join product on stock.product_id=product.product_id
group by stock.product_id,product.pname
```

This way, in your while loop you can have:

```
       while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
           $Productname=$row['pname'];
           $yard=$row['yard']; 
           $office=$row['office']; 
           $Tqnty=$office+$yard;
       ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @nacho, but how can i echo quantity of the office and quantity of the yard? see the second screenshot attached above

Comment: its coming the store id and not the quantity of the product name,, can we echo the quantity of product at office and yard and if there is no quantity it can echo 0 regarding to its product name ? @nacho

Comment: the big concept here is to have the quantity of the office and yard and Total (Office+yard )quantity regarding to products_id

Comment: What is the Q Yard get from?

Comment: Store=1 is office and store=2 is Yard

Comment: I think you can do it, but I don´t use codeigniter, so i don´t know how